# Click on every 'a' tag in page puppeteer

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to get puppeteer to go to all a tags in a page and load them, add them to an array and return it. My puppeteer version is 1.5.0. Here is my code:

```
module.exports.scrapeLinks = async (page, linkXpath) => {

    page.waitForNavigation();
    linksElement = await page.$x(linkXpath);
    var url_list_arr = [];
    console.log(linksElement.length);
    i=1;
    for(linksElementItem in linksElement)
    {
        const linksData = await page.$x('(' + linkXpath + ')[' + (i + 1) +']');
        if (linksData.length > 0) {
            linksData[0].click();
            console.log(page.url());
            url_list_arr.push(page.url());
        } 
        else {
          throw new Error('Link not found');
        }



    }

    return url_list_arr;

};
```

However with this code, I get an

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or
>   not an HTMLElement

I also found out through the docs that is not possible to use the xpath on the page.click function. Is there anyway to achieve this?

It is also okay if there is a function to get all the link from a page, but I couldn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

To get a handle on all `a`-tags in an array:

```
const aTags= await page.$$('a')
```

Loop through them with:

```
for (const aTag of aTags) {...}
```

Inside the loop you can interact with each of these `elementHandle` separately.

Note that

```
await aTag.click()
```

will destroy (garbage collect) all `elementHandles` when the page context is navigated. In this case you need a workaround like loading the initial page inside a loop to always start with a fresh instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  One thing, there is no $click method in 1.5.0 as per the docs. It's click(). The loop is working only for the first time, at the second time,  there is an error `Cannot find context with specified id undefined`.  I think it is because clicking the previous element has changed the page object. Is it possible to workaround this issue?

Comment: (Thanks for spotting the wrong syntax for .click(). I edited my post.)

All elementHandles are destroyed (garbage collected) when their parent context gets navigated.

What you could do though is moving the initial page load into the loop. And each round in the loop you increase a counter N and then jsut click the Nth a-tag. Then you always click on a fresh context of the initial page. Let me know when you need the code to do that.

Comment: Perfect, this explains the problem. So I will load a new page inside the loop. I'll try and let you know, thanks! :)